# how to add loop in variable in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

could you please tell me how to add loop in variable in xslt ?

here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHV/7

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$name"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$name/child">
       row: <xsl:value-of select="row"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

      </hmtl>
```

my `$name` variable has this value

```
 <p>
      <child>
         <row>aa</row>
         <name>poi</name>
      </child>
      <child>
         <row>addda</row>
         <name>noo</name>
      </child>
   </p>
```

I try to get `row` value using loop .But it not working .It is not showing ny value why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables holds a temporary tree fragment and not a `p` element so you need to use `<xsl:for-each select="$name/p/child">` to select the `p` and then the `child` elements.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<xsl:for-each select="$name/child">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="$name//child">
```